# IdentityServer prompting for permissions after login

Tags: identityserver3

I am looking at adding IdentityServer to an existing website / Web API solution, as we are soon adding Mobile applications using Angular & Ionic. As we are going to be calling the Web API from the mobile application, we are looking at adding a STS to the solution.

In all of the samples I have seen for IdentityServer using the Implicit & Hybrid Flow, after the login has been completed, the user is prompted to say which permissions the requesting application can access.

In the current website, you are not asked for this, just your username and password. Is there a way to skip this?

Any insights are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping the consent: Yes, that's part of the client configuration. See the documentation for `Client` and the `RequireConsent` property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies whether a consent screen is required (defaults to true)
/// </summary>
public bool RequireConsent { get; set; }
```

| [Docs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html) |
[Source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Models/Client.cs#L60) |